# Win Server 2008 R2 on VPS crashing 2x daily

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I have been pressed into service as a system admin on a Windows Server 2008R2 VPS that is crashing twice daily at random times. This has been going on for two weeks or more and I have dozens of hours invested in reading logs and learning,,, but just not getting it!! The server is under very light use running one website. I have 46GB free on the HD, 4 GB ram. HD has been defragged. Ram usage creeps up to 2.5 GB and floats around that value. CPU ranges 0-2% as a rule. Running MS SQL Express. DBCC CheckDB returns no errors. The VPS has been in operation for about three years with little trouble until now.

Answer (score 0):

Usially crashes like that are caused by buggy drivers or failing hardware, especially memory.

You may want to enable Crash Minidumps (256K) in `Control Panel/System/Advanced/Boot and Recovery`.

You collect them (they are located at *%SystemRoot%\Minidump*), and analyse with [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html). Most probably you will find one same error for every crash. This will give you additional data and hopefully lead to an answer.

If this doesn't help, write a comment to my answer so I got notified, and explain output.